# data model for tree structure (file system): document model vs graph model

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, orientdb, graph-databases, arangodb

I'm evaluating a nosql solution for implement a file system like structure, with millions of items, where key features have to be:

- speed finding "parents" or "direct childs" or "subtree childs" of an item filtered by n item properties, with page results sorted by item property.

having this requirements i split the problem in 2 task:

1. model the recursive items structure for search childs/subtree childs
2. model the item structure for search over items property

Now the power of nosql schema free is a good feature for store different properties for each file, and this is good for point 2.

I have instead some doubt over point 1 about the pros / cons to use a document database (example mongodb) with a single collection of items and a materialized path design pattern, or using a graph database (example arangodb) with 2 collection: items for data (document collection), and itemsParents for parent-child relation (edge collection) and a graph traverse function.

There are advantages in performance using a graph database for my requirements?

graph traverse is more efficient over materialized path filter to accomplish my task?

If yes, can you explain me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

A graph database would certainly be a great choice for a hierarchical structure like a filesystem.  Speaking specifically of Neo4j you could have a schema such as:

```
(:Folder)-[:IN_FOLDER]->(:Folder)
(:File)-[:IN_FOLDER]->(:Folder)
```

Finding a file or a folder is as simple as the following Cypher:

```
MATCH (file:File {path: '/dir/file'})
RETURN file
```

To find all of the files/folders directly under a folder:

```
MATCH (folder:Folder {path: '/dir'})<-[:IN_FOLDER]-(file_or_folder)
RETURN file_or_folder
```

If you wanted to find all files/folders recursively you could do:

```
MATCH (folder:Folder {path: '/dir'})<-[:IN_FOLDER*1..5]-(file_or_folder)
RETURN file_or_folder
```

The `1..5` adjusts the depth (from one to five levels) which you are searching.

For all of these you'd want an index on the `path` property for both the `Folder` and `File` labels.  Of course you wouldn't need to do it this way, depending on your use-case.

The reason that Neo4j can be so much faster in this case is because once you find a node on disk the relationships can be traversed with just a few file accesses as opposed to searching an entire table or index for each hop.  I recommend checking out the free book [Graph Databases by O'Reilly](http://graphdatabases.com/) for details on the internals of Neo4j.

Comment: If you have any other questions about Neo4j there is an active Slack group here: http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/

Answer (score 11):

Your use case is better served by a multi-model database, which is both a document store and a graph database. With such a data store you can put all your items as vertices in one collection and have the relations for the hierarchy as edges in a separate collection. Additionally, you could store the path with every item and have a sorted index and, if constant time matters, a hash index on the path attribute.

You would get

1. O(1) (constant time) lookup for an item by its path (using the hash index)
2. O(1) lookup for a parent either by a graph neighbour or by a lookup by (truncated) path
3. finding all n direct children in time O(n) using graph neighbours
4. finding a complete subtree by a range lookup in the sorted index in time proportional to the number of items in the result
5. get near arbitrary fast item accesses by adding further secondary indexes

1.-4. is best possible, because the complexity cannot be better than the size of the result set.

Let me explain the performance arguments in a bit more detail:

Cases 1. and 2. are good with both approaches, since you only need a single result, which you can access directly. Whether or not you use a hash index or let a sorted index suffice will probably matter very little.

Case 3. (direct children) is faster with a graph database, since it has "find all direct neighbours" as a very fast primitive. If you rely on the materialized path and a sorted index, you cannot get the direct children with a range query and so it will be slower.

Case 4. (whole subtree) is faster with a materialized path and a range query using a sorted index, since that can just emit (using an iterator if you want) a complete range. A graph database will have to perform a graph traversal which will involve (temporary) data mutations on the server for the enumeration.

The advantage with a multi-model database is that you can **combine** the advantages of the two approaches (3. and 4.) you suggest in a single data store.

One possibility for such a database is the [ArangoDB database](https://arangodb.com).

Disclaimer: I am one of the main developers.

Comment: Please do not hesitate to ask further questions in this Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb